# Onload styling in javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, visibility, hidden

could you help me with the onload function in Javascript?

```
preload.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Could you tell me what the onload version of this would be, in the same type of format as this code?

```
preload.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Where does the onload fit in to this?

Answer (score 1):

`onload` is an eventhandler in Javascript that is fired for the load event of a window.

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

If you wanted to switch the style of some element `onload` you would construct an event handler such as:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var preload = document.getElementById("preload");
  preload.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
};
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onload)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm pretty noob, so bear with me..Does the event handler you posted need anything else to activate it?

Comment: Well it should be in an external script file or in a script tag, follow me?